# Unresolved function or method app | node.js

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('./todo', function (req, res) {});
    app.post('./todo', function (req, res) {});
    app.delete('./todo', function(req , res){});
};
```

I'm using WebStorm 2017.2.5 and Express package 4.16.3.
My issue is `get` method works fine but `post` and `delete` got **"unresolved function or method `post`"** warning.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node-express app.get() marked as unresolved in webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116124/node-express-app-get-marked-as-unresolved-in-webstorm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the express methods list is generated dynamically, and it's not possible to resolve these properties using static code analysis. Running `npm i @types/express` should solve the problem:

[image]

Please read more here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

Answer (score 2):

You need to download and install the "express" library in WebStorm. 
Go to **Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > Libraries > Download**. Find the "express" library and hit **Download and Install**. 
This should work.